# How to use dos's DEBUGs to find a programs interrupts

Tags: dos

How do you find all the interrupts called by a dos program using DEBUG on the command line. I know it probably has something to do with the Search function but whenever I trying something like -s 100:ffff(which i think searches the entire memory segment for "INT") But when I manually Unassemble through the same segment with the u command I can see INT/interrupts being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a better debugger, but if you want to use DOS debug to find INT call, you can try something like:

```
debug program.exe
-d
14C0:0000 ...
....
-s 14C0:0000,FFFF CD
14C0:0007
14C0:000C
-u 14C0:0007
14C0:0007 CD21  INT  21
....
```

First, you find the right segment to search for (by entering **d** command), then you search in that segment for CD (this is machine code for INT mnemonic).  You can disassemble the search result by entering **u** command.

Comment: I agree that this debugger is a little lacking, i`m just following the specs for a homework assignment.